# Google Sign-In: Keeping user signed out if he/she signs out elsewhere

Tags: google-signin

I use Google Sign-In in order to let my users connect their Google Calendar and related services to our web app. The problem is that if a user signs out of her connected account somewhere else, this will revoke access from our app as well.

I understand that this is primarily a user issue, but several of them still expect their Google integration with our app to work even if they are not signed in to the account in question.

Is there any way at all we can achieve this? Does Google Sign-In have something akin to a Refresh Token which will allow us to create a new session even if the user has signed out?

Comment: Silly Question - Does refresh not work?  I use it all of the time with Google.  You may have to use something like 1Pass or LastPass alongside this as well.  LastPass works great.

Comment: Yes, have tried it :( We have reproduced the issue several times with different accounts without fail, so this seems to be by design from Googles side. It does make sense in how Google Sign-In works, anyway. Once they are signed out of their account,  they should be signed out everywhere. Thus, I don't know if it actually makes sense even trying to solve this - it might be better just to go for plain oauth2 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple approaches, we came to the conclusion that this simply is not possible. You should **NOT** use Google SignIn if you need persistent access to a users profile until he/she manually revokes it. The natural choice for that is plain oauth2.